# Mean.js - angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I'm just trying to run mean.js using grunt. Just did the installation steps in http://meanjs.org. But when loaded in localhost, console is showing error

Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Can any one help how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you included angular on the page? are there instructions to run bower for example?

Comment: Yes I included angular on page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like angular is not included on the page.

When the install process is over, npm will initiate a bower install command to install all the front-end modules needed (including angular) for the application

You can run bower manually using

```
bower install --config.interactive=false
```

make sure that angular appears in the `public/lib` folder and included on the page.

Comment: Sorry i did not find any lib folder under public

Comment: did you try running `bower install` ?